# Google Cloud Function in Python: TypeError: post_tweet() missing 1 required positional argument: 'context'

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to set up a Google Cloud Function that mirrors a python script github repository. I have already successfully implemented the function without github mirroring, but for some reason when I test the function a project where I'm using mirroring I get the error listed in the title.

The method header for the function I'm calling in my main.py file is below:

`def post_tweet(data, context):`

I have the `context` param in the header, so I'm not sure why it says I'm missing the argument.

**Edit:** As requested, here is the complete code.

```
import os
import sys
import tweepy

# source: https://www.cookieshq.co.uk/posts/how-to-build-a-serverless-twitter-bot-with-python-and-google-cloud
# docs: 
#  - https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#functions_env_var_set-python
#  - https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/#functions-writing-helloworld-http-python

def setup_api():
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(os.environ.get('CONSUMER_KEY'), os.environ.get('CONSUMER_SECRET'))
    auth.set_access_token(os.environ.get('ACCESS_TOKEN'), os.environ.get('ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET'))
    return tweepy.API(auth)
def post_tweet(data, context):
    api = setup_api()
    tweet = 'Hello, world!'
    status = api.update_status(status=tweet)
    return 'Tweet Posted'
```

**Edit 2:**
To clarify, I have this exact code that runs perfectly fine when I use the Google Cloud Function inline editor. The error listed in the title occurs only when I use the `cloud source repository` option and link it to a git repository.

Comment: As the error, `post_tweet` accepts two arguments but you passed one. Please add full code for better help.

Comment: @Masoud Thanks for the suggestion. The full code is now in the post.

Comment: There is no use of the `data` and `context` argument in your `post_tweet` function.

Comment: The `data` and `context` arguments are required for a Google Cloud Function. The docs I'm referencing are linked in the code comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing around with this some more it looks like the `context` parameter is not passed in when mirroring from a github repo. The method header should only accept a `data` parameter: `def post_tweet(data):`

Answer (score 7):

I think the parameters required depend on your invocation method. If you're using Pub/Sub to trigger the function, then you need `def post_tweet(event, context):`. However if you deploy with a HTTP trigger, only one parameter is needed: `def post_tweet(request):`.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to pass the `--signature-type=cloudevent` or `--signature-type=event` flag to the functions_framework command depending on your runtime. https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/running/calling#cloudevent-function-curl-tabs-storage

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I'm not sure how you call the function but here is a working example based on your example:

```
import os
import sys
import tweepy

# source: https://www.cookieshq.co.uk/posts/how-to-build-a-serverless-twitter-bot-with-python-and-google-cloud
# docs:
#  - https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#functions_env_var_set-python
#  - https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/#functions-writing-helloworld-http-python

from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

def setup_api():
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(os.environ.get(
        'CONSUMER_KEY'), os.environ.get('CONSUMER_SECRET'))
    auth.set_access_token(os.environ.get('ACCESS_TOKEN'),
                          os.environ.get('ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET'))
    return tweepy.API(auth)


def post_tweet():
    api = setup_api()
    tweet = 'Hello, world!'
    status = api.update_status(status=tweet)
    return 'Tweet Posted'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # just for checking if everything goes fine
    print(post_tweet())
```

Then you can deploy it.

```
gcloud functions deploy post_tweet --region europe-west1 --memory=128MB --env-vars-file .env --runtime python37 --trigger-http
```

Comment: The `post_tweet` function does not need to be called in the code. The settings of the Google Cloud Function are configured to call it when triggered.

Comment: In the pythonic way you can just call the post_tweet() to create a new tweet with `data` message, and it seems that google cloud call it without any arguments as in the original example used.

Comment: I don't think this addresses my issue. When I do as you do and remove the parameters from post_tweet, I get the following error when I test the function: `post_tweet() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`

Comment: So it seems that it is passing one argument to `post_tweet()`. Do you know what is this argument or use of?